# How to remove single line transitions from a string, but leave one for double ones?

Tags: java, regex

I count lines from files in string .

```
String testing=newString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)),StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replaceAll("\\r\\n{1}", "");
```

What regular expression or something similar can be used to remove single line transitions, but leave double ones?

That is for example:

the elements in the file go like this:

```
A
1


b
;
d
```

When I do:

```
String testing = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
LinkedList<Character> alphabetList = testing.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I get that the list contains such elements:

```
A
\\r
\\n
\\r
\\n
1
\\r
\\n
b
```

And I need the single ones to be removed , and the single ones replaced with " ".

Comment: Does it mean if there are 2 or more blank lines you need to remove one? Between `af1` and `23131`, the expected string shows one blank line, while there are two in the input.

Comment: Ok, let me guess: `.replaceAll("(\\R{2,})\\R|(\\R)\\R", "$1$2")` works for you, doesn't it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not quite.I'll try to explain when I make my read string ```collectors.ToList``` I have characters: 'A' next '\r' next '\n' then letters again.and in one place twice in a row '\r' '\n' '\r' '\n' and with your method everything remained, but the double was removed.Can you tell me how to make all the single \r \n removed and the double replaced with "  "(whitespace)

Comment: I can't quite get what you are after. [This](https://ideone.com/GrfRgo)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I 'll edit it now to make it clearer

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew edit

Comment: No way is it clearer. Post 1) an exact string literal you have as input, 2) exact string literal you need as output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Here above I have an input file where each character is on its own line,I read the entire file into a string and get that there are now \r\n between the letters, and if there was an empty string in the files, then ```\r\n\r\n```.I add a line to the list and it turns out what is above, and I would like there to be only characters, that is, not ```'a' '\r' '\n'  '\r' '\n' '1' '\r' '\n' 'b'``` so if single \r\n, then it is removed, and if double \r\n\r\n, then replace with a space.that is, ```'A' " '1' 'b'```

Comment: @sln thank you, your function is almost working.Everything is fine, but I put something after ":" "\r""\n" don't know why this is so?

Comment: Run two regex. `(?<![\r\n])(?:\r?\n|\r)(?![\r\n])` then replace with a nothing. Then run `(:\r?\n|\r){2,}` then replace with a space.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str =
        "afaf\r\n"
        + "\r\n"
        + "af1\r\n"
        + "\r\n"
        + "\r\n"
        + "23131";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\r\\n((\\r\\n)+)", "$1"));
}
```

output:

```
afaf
af1

23131
```